# Not having it pretty clear about JSON and its uses on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've got what I consider a very basic question, but I've almost never worked with JSON nor web devolpment (but yes with desktop's with Java), so I'm having really big troubles in my practices with Angular.

You see, I've got this JSON:

```
{
    "imgs": [

        {
            "title": "Primera foto",
            "src": "images/1.gif"
        },

        {
            "title": "Segunda foto",
            "src": "images/2.png"
        },

        {
                                        "title": "Tercera foto",
            "src": "images/3.gif"
        },
        {
            "title": "Cuarta foto",
            "src": "images/4.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Quinta foto",
            "src": "images/5.png"
        },
        {
            "title": "Sexta foto",
            "src": "images/6.gif"
        }
    ]
}
```

I retrieve it using `$http` and `$q` via a service, which works greatly. After that, I save the info in a scope variable in a controller:

```
ctrls.controller('imagesCtrl', ['$scope', 'getJSON', function($scope, getJSON){

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.loadImages = function(){
        $scope.images = getJSON.getImages();
    }

    $scope.loadImages();
    alert($scope.images);

}])
```

... and I try to show it in the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="miApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!--  Importamos las dependencias principales  !-->
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="angular-routeangular-route.js"></script> !-->
        <!--  Importamos nuestros propios archivos (controladores, directivas, etc...) !-->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="directives.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="imagesCtrl">

      <littleImage src="{{image.src}}" ng-repeat="image in images"></littleImage>

    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Nothing appear after the `ng-repeat`, so I guess I'm not accessing correctly to the JSON data. In case you're doubtious, this is the directive I'm trying to use:

```
directives.directive('littleImage', function(){
    return{
        restrict: E,
        scope: {
            src : "@"
        },
        template: "<div><img src="+src+" class='img-responsive' alt='Image'></div>"
        }
});
```

In case there are more doubts about my code, this is my service (pretty straightforward):

```
ctrls.factory('getJSON', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return{
        getImages : getImages
    }   

    function getImages(){
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;

        $http.get("data.json")
           .success(function(data){
                defered.resolve(data);
           })
           .error(function(err){
                defered.reject(err);
           });

        return promise;
    };
}]);
```

Anybody knows what am I doing bad?

**EDIT: **

Thanks for the help so far! You helped me a lot, but there's one last thing: now the directive, somehow, isn't computing correctly, and it doesn't wrap it's template into the actual HTML.

This is the HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">
        {{image.title}}
        <littleImage source="image.src" ></littleImage>
    </div>
```

And this is the directive:

```
directives.directive('littleImage', function(){
return{
    restrict: E,
    scope: {
        source : "="
    },
    template: "<div><img ng-src="+source+" class='img-responsive' alt='Image'></div>"
    }
});
```

Any idea on why it doesn't work?

Comment: Inside your directive you need to use `src='{{src}}'` in your case src will be undefined or you get exception that str is undefined.

Comment: did you tried returning base64 of images instead of their urls in your JSON?

Comment: Please check updated one

Comment: Change littleImage to little-image that's the problem

Comment: Tried it, Jesús, but it keeps failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I voted all your posts because every one of them helped me. Thank you for that!

These were my troubles:

1. I wasn't getting the JSON properly all time, since I use promises. Also, I wasn't accessing to the "imgs" array. Changed my controller function to:

   ```
           $scope.loadImages = function() {
               getJSON.getImages().then(function(data) {
                   $scope.images = data.imgs;
               }, function() {
                   alert("Ha habido un error cargando los datos");
               });
           }
   ```
2. The ng-repeat works better in a different div. Also, as you were saying, the src value must be the variable name, instead of its value (as it was being represented by using the curly braces):

   {{image.title}}
3. As last but not least, my directive was totally wrong. Had to access to the src variable in the scope, using "=", change the src from the `<img>` tag to ng-src, and the last thing that nobody said: instead of writing "src" as its value, it works writing its actual value, via {{src}}:

   directives.directive('littleImage', function(){
   return{
       restrict: "E",
       scope: {
           src : "="
       },
       template: ""
       }
   });

Now it's properly working! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in this line:

```
<littleImage src="{{image.src}}" ng-repeat="image in images"></littleImage>
```

The handlebars aren't required and the repeater needs changed, you can simply use:

```
<littleImage src="image.src" ng-repeat="image in images.imgs"></littleImage>
```

Comment: Maybe this was a thing, but my actual problem is when I try to work with the JSON file. if I do an alert($scope.images) it shows "Object object", which is ok. But I can't access to $scope.images[0], nor $scope.images.imgs[0], per example.

Comment: It's hard to guess that when I can't see what getImages() is returning - try logging this line to the console:  `Object.keys($scope.images)`

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer, note that the repeater has changed to use `images.imgs` - i think this is the fix you need but I'm just double checking now

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in your `<img src="...">` Angular has this directive `ng-src`, because the $scope variable might not be loaded yet when your image tag gets rendered.

Answer (score 1):

you are using [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).Do this change in controller

```
getJSON.getImages().then(function(data) {


    $scope.images = data.imgs;

}, function() {


    //error hanlding part
})
```

Comment: Throws an error: Error: can't convert undefined to object

Comment: Please see the EDIT.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I fixed your edit, if you use a promise, get the data from the promise

Answer (score 1):

Your directive is wrong, you should use the normal binding and use an angular expression in the template: src variable doesn't exists, it's src attributes in scope that exists:

```
directives.directive('littleImage', function(){
return{
    restrict: E,
    scope: {
        src : "="
    },
    template: '<div><img ng-src="src" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></div>'
    }
});
```

oh and also in the template, it is binded by angular expression not by text remove the curly braces:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
  {{image.src}}
  <littleImage src="image.src" ></littleImage>
</div>
```

I slightly change your code to check if the data is well loaded, it should help the debug.

Comment: It now shows up the src correctly! But it doesn't change in the src="image.src"; it does with the curly braces. Thing is, that my directive is somehow not working, it just won't insert the div nor the img.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get images array synchronously, you must get it asynchronously.
you must get image list through promise like this:

```
ctrls.controller('imagesCtrl', ['$scope', 'getJSON', function($scope, getJSON){

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.loadImages = function(){
        getJSON.getImages().then(function (data) {
            $scope.images = data;
        })
    }

    //$scope.loadImages();
    //alert($scope.images);

}])
```

without using of $q and promise way you can using of simple javascript callback to get data from service:

```
services.factory('getJSON',['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        getImages: function (cb) {
            $http({
                url: "YOUR_IMAGES_LIST_ADDRESS",
                method: 'GET'
            }).success(function (data) {
                cb(data);
            }).error(function (error) {
                cb(null, error)
            })
        }
    }
}]);

ctrls.controller('imagesCtrl', ['$scope', 'getJSON', function($scope, getJSON){

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.loadImages = function(){
        getJSON.getImages(function (data, error) {
            if(error) {
                //show error 
            }
            $scope.images = data;
        })
    }

    //$scope.loadImages();
    //alert($scope.images);

}])
```

there is another alternative simplest way :), just return $http in your service:

```
services.factory('getJSON',['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        getImages: function () {
            return $http({
                url: "YOUR_IMAGES_LIST_ADDRESS",
                method: 'GET'
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

service return promise object of $http.

```
ctrls.controller('imagesCtrl', ['$scope', 'getJSON', function($scope, getJSON){

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.loadImages = function(){
        getJSON.getImages().then(function (response) {
            $scope.images = response.data;
        })
    }

    //$scope.loadImages();
    //alert($scope.images);

}])
```